# Extract text of a certain color ignoring the rest

Tags: python, python-tesseract

[image]I have image and need text from that image. Only need to convert  time that is in yellow color and need to ignore the background text.
I am using textract with Python

I tried to convert rgb to grey but still getting the garbage result. Its reading data rom the background

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

image_file = Image.open('timeline_with_background_text.png')

image_file = image_file.convert('L') # convert image to black and white
image_file.save('question.png')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image_file, lang = 'eng',config='-psm 6')
print(text)
```

From the image just need to convert time that is displays in Yellow color like "34:53"

Comment: The idea is to apply an orange filter prior to passing the image to tesseract... What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with the ImageMagick library in python.

If your yellow text will always be the exact same yellow, perhaps you could do something like this.

First, get the hex value of the yellow colour you want to keep. (lets say its #ffff00).

Then, use image magic to fill any colour EXCEPT that #ffff00 colour with black. That should leave you with an image that only shows your time.

`convert original.png -fill black +opaque '#ffff00' onlyTime.png`

https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#opaque

In case the yellow colour is not always exactly the same, you can try to play around with the `-fuzz` option.

https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#fuzz

---

Using the image you provided, I tried the following:

`.\convert.exe C:\YLD2g.png -fill black -fuzz 20% +opaque '#c0861e' c:\onlyTime2.png`

and the result was:

[onlyTime2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5L5h.png)

That should be good enough for tesseract

Comment: thanks Ziptron, I tried with multiple shades of Yellow but every time it converted image to black, I used below commands.
    `convert original.png -fill black +opaque '#c0861e' onlyTime2.png`
    `convert original.png -fill black +opaque '#617614' onlyTime3.png`
    `convert original.png -fill black +opaque '#c19d65' onlyTime4.png`

Comment: Try including the fuzz parameter (That second link I posted). Its probably hard to get the exact value of yellow, but fuzz will let you choose colours a certain specified distance away from the colour that you think best matches.

Comment: is there anything I can do with testract

Comment: I just tried ````.\convert.exe C:\YLD2g.png -fill black -fuzz 20% +opaque '#c0861e' c:\onlyTime2.png ```` and it worked for me.